# How to lock a browser with a password/passcode on iPhone?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, password, privacy, web-browser

Is there a way to make a Web browser on iPhone 11 Pro other than Safari to be lockable with a password or a passcode, even by any extension? That is, when you launch the browser, a password is required. The password isn’t asked again while the browser remains open, even in the background. If you close the browser app, then it will ask for the password at the next launch.

Screen Time blocks all browsers but I need to lock only one web browser, not every browser.

Firefox has passcode feature, but only for saved passwords, not opening the app itself.

Additionally, I look for a solution that doesn’t require me to set up a passcode, Touch ID or something similar on the whole iPhone. I want my iPhone to remain unlocked, except for the browser.

Comment: See if Firefox focus can fulfil some of the privacy needs? @hydro Or parental controls ?

Comment: @ankii the parental controls provide only a workaround with Screen Time that is awkward for my case; and in Firefox Focus I didn’t find anything related to my question.

Comment: What is "But I need to lock only a Web browser, and not even any browser." supposed to mean? As currently written it makes no sense at all!

Comment: Sorry, @user3439894 English isn’t my first language. I meant that I don’t need to lock _every_ browser, but rather I am looking for some single browser that can be locked this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iCab Mobile](http://www.icab-mobile.de/) has had this feature [since at least 2012](https://www.engadget.com/2012/09/30/secure-browsing-on-ios-in-safari-or-icab-mobile/).

iCab » Settings » Account

*(iCab is, by far, the most feature-rich browser on iOS. I’ve referred to it as “Safari Pro” for many years.)*

Comment: Yes, iCab does almost what I need. The only exception is that I have to log out manually every time before closing the app. If I forget to log out, then next time iCab opens the last used account without prompting a password. But it is not a big deal for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in means to secure only web browsers on iOS with a passcode that wouldn't also affect the entire device.

Consider erasing the iPhone and enrolling it in an MDM, or mobile device manager, such as [Jamf Now](https://signup.jamfnow.com/?r=1ef198c760ff4bf0a1aa1e98c98c9233).

To proceed, you'll need to use Apple's free [Configuration Manager 2](https://support.apple.com/apple-configurator).

While you can enroll an iOS device into an MDM (not just Jamf) without 'supervising' it, to have the greatest amount of control over the device you should set it as supervised. Note that you cannot restore an unsupervised iOS backup from iTunes, Configurator or iCloud to a supervised device.

Once supervised, enroll the device into Jamf Now and choose a 'blueprint' of security options, including remotely managing ScreenTime and disabling the installation of other apps.

---

Comment: This might work, but it's way overkill when iCab has this feature built-in.